# How can I hold my running function until I click the button in c++ form?

Tags: c++, forms, recursion, event-handling

I am using .net framework 4 and visual studio 2010.
I am working with c++ form.
My code is something like  that:

```
int k = 0;

void writeFunction(int &k){
    ++k;
    textbox1->text = Convert::toString(k);

    //i want to suspend writeFunction in there, until i click the button1 which is on Form1 
    //because i don't want to stop function, it has to wait to click

    //after i clicked the button1 , the program continue to run code here

   writeFunciton(k);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just call this function: `void writeFunction(int &k){ ++k;    textbox1->text = Convert::toString(k); }` inside your button click handler?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more details about your program? What framework are you using to generate the form, and how do button presses interact with your code?

For example, if you're using Qt then you could use signals and slots to link pressing the button with your method. Depending on the framework there might be other appropriate answers.

Generally I would recommend using a threading library to synchronize your code.

Comment: I am using .net framework 4 and visual studio 2010. Actually i found a result when i call my function. i want to change text of TextBox when i found a result and call my function again when i want to click the button which is on my form. When i call the function i have to wait it to click the something on form because of that I have to suspend my function to click the button, and call this function again.

Comment: I tried to synchronize my code with threading library but i failed

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to suspend a GUI function..instead of that use operation state variable in your form class such as

```
enum OperationState 
 {
  os_normal,
  os_pointselection,
  os_event1,...
 }
```

After you call textbox->=...
swicth to selection state and by using this state track mouse states like click after mouseclick check for os_selection state,then continue you duty..

Comment: The difficulty of problem is that a recursive function.  If i don't click the button, it has to wait for me to click button. If I don't click the button, then program continue to run code, i don't want this situation

Comment: for all of your purposes this is how to handle GUI events with continuous user interaction....just hold operational states and/or window states then switch them to track events(if you wish you may lock some interactions and force user to trigger this event) and got input and return back to normal states..

Comment: Thank you Semih, I will try to do as you told